# Touchpad working intermitently on Kubuntu 17.04

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, lenovo, synaptics

I've got Kubuntu 17.04 installed on my Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro and I'm having some weird issues with the touchpad. It doesn't seem to be consistently working. Sometimes after a boot, it works just fine. Other times it's recognized in xinput but doesn't seem to respond to any sort of motion. The laptop's touch screen always seems to work, however.

I'll post my `xinput` in a second (on a separate computer right now) and am more than happy to provide any other diagnostic information upon request.

Thanks!

EDIT1:

```
$ xinput        
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

EDIT2: Possible correlation/causation but it seems this occurs after the OS starts up to a TTY rather than directly into a DE. Not sure why it sometimes boots up to a raw TTY but it happens from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

When you boot up next time and it does not work try to open and copy `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file to another location.

In that file search for `SynPS/2` by pressing Ctrl + F. If something shows up post that "area" containing information here.

good luck!